# Time Picker Dialog in Android studio

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, time

trying to solve my timer error in android stuido.
i have 2 xml text views where one is start time and one is finsih time
a user must choose there start and finish time to fill in the details
i have most the code correct just cant figure out this one line

also would like if possible i know its already working but for my date picker how do i make say "Friday 3/04/2020"

here is my main java class

```
            public class ChoseSession extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
            {


                private static final String TAG = "ChooseSession";
                private TextView displayDate;
                private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;

                private TextView displayStartTime;
                private TextView displayFinishTime;
                private  TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mSTimeSetListener;
                private  TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mFTimeSetListener;


            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                public Button confirmbookingBTN;
                public void returnMain()
                {
                    confirmbookingBTN = (Button)findViewById(R.id.confirmBooking);
                    confirmbookingBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            Intent book = new Intent(ChoseSession.this, Results.class);
                            startActivity(book);
                        }
                    });
                }
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
                {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chose_session);
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    returnMain();
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    displayStartTime = findViewById(R.id.startTimeView);
                    displayFinishTime = findViewById(R.id.finishTimeView);

                    displayStartTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                            int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                            TimePickerDialog timedialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getContext())););
                            timedialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable((new ColorDrawable((Color.TRANSPARENT))));
                            timedialog.show();
                        }
                    });

                    displayFinishTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                            int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                            TimePickerDialog timedialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getContext())););
                            timedialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable((new ColorDrawable((Color.TRANSPARENT))));
                            timedialog.show();
                        }
                    });

                    mSTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
                        {
                            displayStartTime.setText((hourOfDay+":"+minute));
                        }
                    };

                    mFTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
                        {
                            displayFinishTime.setText((hourOfDay+":"+minute));
                        }
                    };





            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    displayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateView);
                    displayDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {
                                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                                int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                                int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                                int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(ChoseSession.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth, mDateSetListener, year, month, day);
                                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                                dialog.show();
                            }
                        });

                    mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int y, int m, int d)
                        {
                            m = m + 1;
                            Log.d(TAG, "onDataSet: date: " + y + "/" + m + "/" + d);

                            String date = d+"/"+m+"/"+"/"+y;
                            displayDate.setText(date);
                        }
                    };

            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    Spinner sSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinnerSessionChoosing);
                    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.sessionNames, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    sSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                    sSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                }

                private Context getContext()
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String textSession = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), textSession, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
                {

                }



            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            }
```

my XML

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/finishTimeView"
                android:layout_width="161dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="99dp"
                android:text="Choose Finish Time"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/confirmBooking"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/timefinishText"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/startTimeView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/startTimeView"
                android:layout_width="161dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:text="Choose Start Time"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/finishTimeView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/timestartText"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dateView" />
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dpjul_MI5RFvhGJt--gtVl3Hpv3PPvwP/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer to the java time dialog

```
                             displayStartTime = findViewById(R.id.startTimeView);
                    displayFinishTime = findViewById(R.id.finishTimeView);

                    displayStartTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            final int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                            final int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                            TimePickerDialog sTimePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(tContext, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
                                {
                                    displayStartTime.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);
                                }
                            },hour, min, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(tContext));
                            sTimePickerDialog.show();
                        }
                    });

                    displayFinishTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            final int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                            final int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                            TimePickerDialog fTimePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(tContext, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
                                {
                                    displayFinishTime.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);
                                }
                            },hour, min, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(tContext));
                            fTimePickerDialog.show();
                        }
                    });
```